# Перевернутая камера на андроид приложении?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. Ребят такой вопрос. Сейчас практикуюсь работать с камерой на Андроид, но есть один небольшой вопрос. Когда камера включается и передает снимок обратно, то фото перевернутое. Скриншот вот он!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код вызова камеры.

```
Intent intentAttachPhoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getImagePath());
            imagePath = uri.getPath();
            intentAttachPhoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            startActivityForResult(intentAttachPhoto, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Ну а потом полученно изображение вставляю в imageView. Подскажите, это глюк эмуляторов что так работает или где то накосячил?

p.s. Мою заспанную морду чур не обсуждать)))

Comment: Андроид. Там **нет** и краткого.

Comment: А на устройстве так же?

Comment: можно смотреть exif фото и разворачивать нормально

Comment: @duddeniska я так понял, что камера возвращает перевернутое изображение? А сама камера запускается в нужном orientation?

Comment: Да, на сколько я помню это зависит от девайса. Какой у тебя?

Answer (score 1):

Да есть такая проблема в Android. Это из за exif flags которые указывают ориентацию фото. Но переписать эти exif flags не возможно. Самый простой способ для решения проблемы это посмотреть текущею ориентацию и если надо провернуть фото (Bitmap).

Вот мой пример:

```
 public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap srcBitmap, String path) {
        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, String.valueOf(0));
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        Bitmap destBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0, srcBitmap.getWidth(),
                srcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return destBitmap;
    }
```

*srcBitmap* - фото которое будем поворачивать, *path* - дорога к нашему фото в памяти девайся (нужно для получения exif flags). И в конце получаем развернутое фото.